# Cmake fails on username with '#'

Tags: cmake

I am working with a CMake (version 2.8.12) script (CMakeLists.txt) that worked on a previous computer (and probably still does). The problem seems to be that my username on my newer computer now contains a `#`. The CMake script now fails with this report:

```
"add_custom_command called with OUTPUT containing a '#'. This character is not allowed."
```

The parameter `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` contained in this line:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DBSTYPEDEFS.F77 COMMAND ${MKDBSTYPEDEFS_EXE} DEPENDS {MKDBSTYPEDEFS_EXE})
```

expands out to include my user-name as part of the full pathname.

Q: Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you change your username? Or move your source code to somewhere outside your home directory?

Comment: Changing the username is not possible (domain admins won't allow this). But your simple suggestion to move the code to another location was simple and worked. Embarrassed I didn't think of this myself. Thank you!

Comment: Great! For the sake of completeness I threw my suggestion in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot simply change your username on the machine, try moving the repository to another location on the machine.

If you current have the repository `repo1` in your home directory, you'll get an expansion to something like this:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT /home/don#robinson/repo1/generated_files/DBSTYPEDEFS.F77 COMMAND ${MKDBSTYPEDEFS_EXE} DEPENDS {MKDBSTYPEDEFS_EXE})
```

which was causing your error. Moving the code to somewhere else, say `/usr/local/repo1`, the expansion in `add_custom_command` now looks like this:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT /usr/local/repo1/generated_files/DBSTYPEDEFS.F77 COMMAND ${MKDBSTYPEDEFS_EXE} DEPENDS {MKDBSTYPEDEFS_EXE})
```

which should remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your script likely will fail when ran on any directory whose full path contains the hash symbol. Similarly, for the less-than and greater-than sign.

Since your username contains the hash symbol, you either have to change your username or to move the directory to a location whose path does not contain the hash symbol. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0053.html for other disallowed characters. This is CMP0053.

If you want to keep your hashtagged username, the process will be more complicated, but it is something in the lines of

```
set(varname "otherwise & disallowed $ characters")
message("${${varname}}")
```